# crontab doesn't work for an executable

Tags: cron, wakeup

I am trying to put my pc to sleep for a minute and then wakeup every 5 minutes and I used the command

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m mem -s 60
```

to achieve this and it works just fine.

But when I try to do this through an executable compiled from the code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
system("rtcwake -m mem -s 60");
return 0;

}
```

in my home folder and changing crontab to

```
*/5 * * * * /home/****/./a.out
```

where `a.out` is executable for the C code provided above, it doesn't do anything.

I can see crontab executing  `a.out` using `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` periodically in every 5 minutes. But my PC doesn't go in a sleep state.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure that `system` command manage to find the `rtcwake` please update your C code to have the *full path* of the program:

```
system("/usr/sbin/rtcwake -m mem -s 60");
```